# Joomla administrator page 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-403

I know this question has been posted a few times already, however I feel that the answers do not quite relate to my problem.

I am trying to admin an existing Joomla webpage, however it seems that the previous admin did something that forbids me from accessing the /administrator section on the page. When I try to enter the admin section using `sitename.com/administrator`or `sitename.com/administrator/index.php`, I get `403 Forbidden`.

I checked the site contents through FTP (which I can access fine) and it seems `jSecure` plugin is not installed - therefore the admin page should be accessible through `/administrator`, right? The file permissions for the `/administrator` folder were 705, I tried changing them to 775, no change. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Can you provide more details. This is not enough to help you out. I suggest you to download this https://github.com/ForumPostAssistant/FPA/zipball/en-GB and as you are able to access ftp you can upload fpa-en.php to your joomla site. Access it through itename.com/fpa-en.php. Further details you can find here https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced. You can then post the data here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seem to be an issue with config in Joomla, it might be better to ask at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quickly diagnose this, try the following in order; stop when you find one that works, and revert changes one by one until you find the single one that's responsible for the problem. Any modifications to the site's security is to be avoided to prevent weakening your site too much.

1. Find the following files, and rename them: (if you are using apache)

   - /.htaccess
   - /administrator/.htaccess

**(if this is the case, you may have either code that's incompatible with the current Apache version, or instructions to explicitly prevent access)**

2. chmod the /administrator to 777 (and revert immediately if it doesn't work) **(in this case, it's a permission problem, just make sure the user running the site has read access to the /administrator folder and subfolders)**
3. re-apply the Joomla Upgrade package to restore original files in place **(you have compromised files)**
4. check out the /logs/ and /administrator/logs folders, the file error.php may contain more info **(at least you know Joomla works! find more info therein)**
5. check out your webserver error log. **(find more info there)**

Comment: Thank you! Turns out renaming .htaccess did the trick. To be honest I did not notice that there was another .htaccess inside the administrator folder, which contained that access to /administrator was to be granted to only one IP.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Jsecure or Jsecure light from the extensions table in phpMyAdmin by changing enable from 1 to 0, This corrected it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your installation path.
I used C-Panel for installing Joomla. By default selected root folder was "portal",so correct path to my page was not www.mydomain.org/, but www.mydomain.org/portal/
I have no idea why admin console was working anyway. Very confusing.
I have reinstalled my page again and ensured that nothing was entered for "Directory (Optional)"